# File in Android internal storage not readable after update

Tags: android, file, manifest, updates

I have an application on the google play store. In this application I save some data in a file (database would be better but would mean more work right now). This works perfectly but the problem is that when I'm running version 2 for example and I save data in a file, I can get it back. But if I then update to version 3, data isn't loaded but the file still exist in the applications 'files' directory. This file is saved in the internal storage of the device. Now I don't know why this happens but I read on the internet that another sharedUserId could be the cause, but I don't have any sharedUserId in my manifest. I know that Android will then generate one, but is this one always the same? Even if the app is compiled on another computer?
Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Some code I use to read and write to the file:

To write:

```
try {
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(object);
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LogUtils.e(IoUtils.class.getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
        } finally {

        }
```

To read:

```
try {
            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
            ObjectInputStream is;
            is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Serializable objectOut = (Serializable) is.readObject();
            is.close();
            return objectOut;
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            LogUtils.e(IoUtils.class.getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LogUtils.e(IoUtils.class.getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            LogUtils.e(IoUtils.class.getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
```

After the update nothing seems to get out of that file but I don't get any error either. With a ROOT file explorer I can go to /data/data/myApp/files/ and there I find the file who has the same size as before the update.

Comment: "I know that Android will then generate one, but is this one always the same?" -- yes, for a given device. "Even if the app is compiled on another computer?" -- yes, this should not matter. Android is the one creating the user ID, not the development tools. What make and model of device is this?

Comment: Tested it on 2 devices and both have the issue

Comment: OK... what makes and models are these, then?

Comment: Samsung galaxy tab 2 and OnePlus One, but a lot of users reported this issue. I only tested it with those 2 devices.

Comment: Internal storage is used by literally a million apps successfully. You must be doing something unusual, though off the top of my head, I have no idea what. You might consider providing a [mcve] demonstrating both your problem, your crash, and how you are determining that the files are actually there.

Comment: Yes I know but I can't find out what I'm missing, I'll edit my post with some code

Comment: `After the update nothing seems to get out of that file`. Aha now i read that the file is found but it contains unusefull data. That is something else as letting us think that the file could not be found when you say `and there I find the file`. And of course the file is readable. Otherwise you could not open the stream. VEVY VERY confusing post.

Comment: Never said the file couldn't be found, my guess is that the file can't be opened by the app or something like that. I opened the file on my computer before and after the update and both files are EXACTLY the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializable without any customization,  should not be used for long term storage, as the format of the object may change between app versions. I would assume you added one variable to the object in the new version, (or a Library object changed,) and therefore your  Serializable is broke.
What you should do is use custom serialization by overwriting functions

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException`

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;

private void readObjectNoData() throws ObjectStreamException;
```

To retrieve the old data, change the serialization to read exactly the old format. You should also put in the future some version identifier to the serialization, so that you can correctly read it.
All this is very messy, and usually you are much better off saving to json (or XML), which will be much more robust.

Comment: I will check that out! Thanks

Comment: The package name changed between 2 updates, can that be the cause?

Comment: Is it possible to store parcelable objects in a File?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue may be omitting using serialVersionUID on your Serialized objects, like this:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2671479145551722098L;
```